# Redis & Java in a multithreaded application help!

Tags: java, multithreading, transactions, redis

We have an application which is currently threaded (about 50 threads) to process transactions.

We have setup a redis database and using `DECRBY` to deduct credits from a users account.

Here is an example of the process:

```
1. Get amount of credits for this transaction
2. Get current credit amount from from Redis: GET <key>
3. If amount of credits exceeds amount cost of transaction continue
4. DECRBY the transaction amount from Redis.
```

The issue i have here is obvious, when the users credits reaches 0, it does fail the transaction (good), but it lets about 10-20 transactions through because of the threading.

I have thought of setting up `WATCH, MULTI, EXEC` with Redis, and then retry, but won't this cause a bottleneck (I think its called race conditions) because the threads will be constantly fighting to complete the transaction.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you want us to confirm that adding transactions/synchronization to your code (which is absolutely required for correctness, as you seem to know), will possibly introduce contention and therefore potentially hurt performance ? Yes it will. What exactly is the point of the question?

Comment: What I would like to know is if I use WATCH, MULTI, EXEC, with retries is this the best way of doing things? Also, confirming the hurt in performance due to using this method.

Answer (score 2):

Locking is what you need. Since DB locks are expensive, you can implement a simple locking scheme in Redis using SETNX and also avoid race conditions. It's well explained here - http://redis.io/commands/setnx. But you still need to implement retries at application level.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the most conventional way of doing it IMO (most usual way is probably to use a lock in a RDBMS), but using `WATCH, MULTI, EXEC` looks akin to [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) and it doesn't seem too weird to me.

I'd assume that the author of Redis intended `WATCH` to be used like this. Performance implication obviously depends on how this thing is implemented (which I don't know), but my bet is that it will perform pretty good.

This is because it seems likely that there will be very less to almost no contention for the same keys in your situation (what is the chance of a user frantically issuing transactions for him/herself?), the success rate for the first swap operation will be really good. So the retry will only happen in very rare cases. Since Redis seems to be a credible framework, they also probably know what they are doing (i.e. less contention = easy job for Redis, thus it can probably handle it!).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use Redis based Lock object implementation for Java provided by [Redisson](https://redisson.org) framework instead of retrying with WATCH-MULTI commands. Working with WATCH-MULTI involves unnecessary requests to Redis during each attempt which works much slower than already acquired lock.

Here is the code sample:

```
Lock lock = redisson.getLock("transationLock");
lock.lock();
try {
  ... // instructions
} finally {
   lock.unlock();
}
```